# How can we set approvals as not required in Workflow?

Tags: workflow, servicenow, orchestration

Scenario is as below

Users are selecting multiple choices through which they will get added in certain groups in AD.

Now those multiple choices are having certain group.

We have created a workflow for it but the issue is if one of the group member is approving the request other are still in "requested" state and we wanted to move them to "not required" as one approval is enough and we wanted to move the workflow.

Would appreciate if anyone can help on the same!!

-- I have already checked the BR - "SNC - Moot user approvals for group" its is wrt user in one group only means anyone can approve and for rest it will be "not required"